# How to protect api routes from users who are not admins using Laravel and jwt-auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

i am new to both Laravel and Stackoverflow so i apologize if my question is not formatted correctly. Any tips with regards to this would be greatly appreciated.

I recently managed to implemented token authentication on my Laravel API using jwt-auth.

I am able to protect my api routes using the jwt-auth middleware to ensure that the specific user has received a token (logged in).

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function() {

  // List Books
  Route::get('books', 'BookController@index');

  )};
```

The JWT is created in a controller called APILoginController that i created containing:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
{

    // check the users credentials
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }
    // the users credentials are correct - return web token
    $user = Auth::user();

    return response()->json(compact('token', 'user')) ;
}
```

I have added a is_admin field to my user table

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('is_admin');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

i was hoping that i would be able to use this field to protect certain routes from regular user where is_admin = 0 and only allow admins (is_admin = 1) to access them. I have no idea if this is the right way to go about this, but it seemed the simplest.

Any help or guidance would be GREATLY appreciated as i have been struggling with this for quite some time. Most of the tutorials i come across seem to create another table with roles but this seems abit overkill and complicated for my skill level and the application i am trying to create.

Kind regards,
Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is write your own middleware that checks if the user is an admin or not

```
php artisan make:middleware checkAdmin
```

This command will place a new CheckAdmin class within your app/Http/Middleware directory

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class checkAdmin
{

      public function handle($request, Closure $next)
      {

           //get admin value of user from database

           if ($adminValue != 1) {
               return redirect('home');
           }

           return $next($request);
     }

}
```

now add you middleware to all the admin only routes

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
   //
})->middleware(CheckAdmin::class);
```

For more about middleware in Laravel see the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Answer (score 1):

I usually use Passport that comes with Laravel but I think it is pretty similar.

You can either create a custom middlewere that would verify what kind of user is trying to access the endpoint. In your case, it would verify if the user is is_admin => 1. You would have something like this :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'is_admin']], function() {
```

Your other option would be to define a scope to your token when the user first request it. I don't know if that is possible with jwt-auth but you would then have something like this :

```
->middleware('scopes:admin');
```

Hope that helped !